# How to populate a Pandas dataframe with list elements while keeping a column same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` which contains many rows and 2 columns like this:

```
| Query | Description |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First sentence   |  First description           |
| Second sentence  | Second description            |
```

I have created a method `new_sentences(query)` which takes in a Query sentence and generates `n` more relevant sentences out of it. The goal is to create a new dataframe which is made up of the original dataframe + the new sentences which are obtained by the `new_sentences(query)`  method. This method returns a list of new sentences like this given a Query e.g. for the first sentence in the original dataframe
`["Generation 1 for first sentence","Generation 2 for first sentence",..."Generation n for first sentence"]` etc.
Similar holds for other passed sentences (though the list returned can contain different number of elements for each passed Query).

The description should remain same for the new sentences corresponding to same type of Query. For example:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  new_sentences = new_sentences(str(df['Query'].iloc[i]))
  #Append the new_sentences but keep description same.
```

The output expected is like this:

```
| Query | Description |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First sentence   |  First description           |
| Generation 1 for first sentence   |  First description           |
| Generation 2 for first sentence   |  First description           |
| Second sentence  | Second description            |
| Generation 1 for second sentence   |  Second description           |
| Generation 2 for second sentence   |  Second description           |
....
```

etc.

So the idea is to populate the dataframe with these new sentences for Queries (besides the old ones already there), so as to have a larger dataframe. I tried to follow a looping approach and also using `iterrows` for iterating on the dataframe, but am not sure how to keep the descriptions same for new generated sentences. Any help and guidance/advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['hello', 'how'],
                  ['are', 'you']], columns=['Query', 'Description'])
df
    Query   Description
0   hello   how
1   are     you
```

and taking a dummy `new_sentences` function, where you can return the new sentences along with the original sentence as a list.

```
def new_sentences(x):
    return [x['Query'], x['Query'][::-1]]
```

And then you can use `apply` along rows(axis=1) the function

```
df['Query'] = df.apply(new_sentences, axis=1)
df
        Query       Description
0   [hello, olleh]  how
1   [are, era]      you
```

Now, you just have to `explode` the list and do the required formatting

```
(df.set_index('Description')['Query'] # setting temporary index for exploding
 .explode().reset_index()
 .reindex(['Query', 'Description'], axis=1)) # ordering the columns

    Query   Description
0   hello   how
1   olleh   how
2   are     you
3   era     you
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer- I have accepted the answer and its easy to understand and helpful. However, I am facing the problem that I am getting the error "TypeError: must be str, not bool" with the df.apply() command. I think that this is because of issues applying the function to the new_sentences() function? My new_sentences function returns a list of sentences in your format - old, new. Does that mean that the problem is new_sentences() is not being applied to the dataframe Query column values? My new_sentences are returned by applying the method on Query column values. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. Earlier, I used the wrong column names inside the function. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by conversion to lists:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Query': ['how healthy are you', 'how wealthy is your father'],
                   'Description': ['question about you', 'question about your dad']})

#a sample function that slices each query to produce two new queries
def new_sentences(query):
    return [query[:11], query[12:]]

old_queries = df1['Query'].tolist()
descrips = df1['Description'].tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[new, descrips[i]] for i, q in enumerate(old_queries)
                    for new in new_sentences(q)], columns=['Query', 'Description'])

print(df1)
print(df2)

#original df1:
                        Query              Description
0         how healthy are you       question about you
1  how wealthy is your father  question about your dad 

#new df2
            Query              Description
0     how healthy       question about you
1         are you       question about you
2     how wealthy  question about your dad
3  is your father  question about your dad
```